# How is OpenMP "auto" schedule implemented in gcc?

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, g++, openmp, scheduling

The OpenMP documentation for `schedule` clause says that, when `schedule(auto)` is specified, then the decision regarding the scheduling is delegated to compiler or runtime system.

How does the compiler (E.g, gcc) decide the scheduling? Does it choose from one of the `static, dynamic, guided` or will it have its own algorithm for choosing a schedule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In libgomp, the default OpenMP runtime library shipped with gcc, `auto` simply maps to `static`. There is no magic.

This is commented in the code as:

```
/* For now map to schedule(static), later on we could play with feedback
 driven choice.  */
```

That comment has been there for 10 years. You can look for `GFS_AUTO` in [`loop.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/loop.c) and [`loop_ull.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/loop_ull.c)